# Redirect all subdomain to a specific file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am new to this htaccess . So please help me to find a solution .

Lets say i have a domain name = example.com

Now i want when any subdomain is entered it will open a particular file , For example

```
demo.example.com >> Will redirect >> demo.example.com/test.php

check.example.com >> Will redirect >> check.example.com/test.php

anything.example.com >> Will redirect >> anything.example.com/test.php
```

Now that test.php should be in website root folder , means the structure should be like this

For this i have already created a wild card subdomain as the same path as the main domain .

Can this be done via htaccess .

Thanks a lot in advance .

Comment: Have you also configured the `virtualhost` of the given domain to accept wildcard or how are you connecting the sub domains to the web server? DNS is just one step.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /sites/test.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sites/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,its working fine.Now demo.example.com >> Will redirect >> demo.example.com/test.php.That test.php is not in the website root directory , so i added a /sites/test.php to your code and its working fine.Now the problem is when i load aything.example.com >> It loads Public_html/sites/test.php which is absolutely fine . But there are other files in that /sites directory . So if i want to access them like anything.example.com/check.php >> Its not loading the check.php which is there in public_html/sites/ folder , but its loading from Website root.Any solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the htaccess file in all of your document root folders:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /test.php [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser so that the "/test.php" shows up in the location bar, include a `R` flag in the square brackets:  `[L,R]`, or a `[L,R=301]` if you want the redirect to be permanently cached.